# Given a set of 6 numbers, can 3 of them be reversibly represented as even numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a set of 6 arbitrary numbers between the range of 0 - 8 inclusive, i.e.

`2, 5, 0, 4, 1, 7`
(duplicates are allowed)

Is there a way the first 3 numbers can be *encoded* or represented as even numbers within the same range, in such a way that they can be reversed back to their original numbers?

Specifically, I'm asking for a procedure or function which, on input any list of $6$ numbers from $0$ to $8$, say $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6$, returns a list $b_1, b_2, b_3, a_4, a_5, a_6$ where $b_1,b_2,b_3$ are even numbers in the same range.

If this is impossible, would it be possible to do given that there were a total of 9 numbers rather than just 6 (still encoding only the first 3)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you are only encoding the first 3 numbers, then what is the point of having the other 3 there? And what do you mean "represented as even numbers within the same range"?

Comment: @6005 The other 3 are also just arbitrary numbers within the same range, I was thinking they could / would somehow be used to perhaps encode the first 3. And by represented as even numbers within the same range, I mean can the first 3 numbers essentially just be encoded into even numbers between the range of 0 - 8. Sorry for the confusion here.

Comment: How can they be used to encode the first 3, what does that even mean? And to my latter question, you just repeated the statement but didn't clarify it.

Comment: @6005 I'm not exactly sure how they'd be used, that is the main point of my question. They don't necessarily _need_ to be used. I just want to take a set of 6 numbers, say 4, 5, 1, 6, 7, 0 - and have it transformed into say 6, 2, 4, 6, 7, 0 - whereby in this example the first 3 are now even. But in a way we can then get back the original values. Obviously, this is just an example with made-up values.

Comment: @Harry Thanks for clarifying, the example explains what you want, and I updated your question to make it clear.

Comment: The reason it wasn't clear before is, no one knows what you mean by "encoded" -- encoded as how many even numbers? And it wasn't clear you leave the last 3 numbers on there in the encoding.

Comment: @6005 thank you for making my question clearer. I'm sorry for using confusing terms.

Comment: the last question would be obvious if the list with the 3 even numbers was order free ( sorted as we wish ). The sort may contain $3!$ states while we need $2^3$ states to find the original values of the even numbers. We know that  $2^3 > 3! $ but $2^4 < 4!$ ... remain the cases where a number occurs more than one time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding you ask for is impossible, with $6$ numbers or with $9$.

Consider with $6$ numbers. Then, in particular, your encoding needs to take any list $a, b, c, 1, 2, 3$ where $a,b,c$ are between $0$ and $8$, and return a list $a', b', c', 1, 2, 3$ where $a', b', c'$ are $0, 2, 4,$ or $8$. There are $9^3 = 729$ possible triples $(a,b,c)$, but only $4^3 = 64$ possible output triples $(a',b',c')$, according to your specification, so you cannot possibly assign one output to every input without ending up with an irreversible (or *not one-to-one*) encoding.

The same argument applies if there are $9$ numbers in the list, or any other amount.

**Edit:** Of course, if you allow the encoded list to have additional terms then it would be possible. For example, if you allow the list $2, 5, 0, 4, 1, 7$ to be encoded as a list of ten integers where the first seven are even and the last three are $4, 1, 7$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are allowed to alter the last three numbers, they serve no function.  If you are allowed to alter them, you can trivially encode the first three by taking $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6$ to $0,0,0,a_1, a_2, a_3$